# PowerShell v4 - Archiving and Extracting New & Existing Zip Files

Tags: powershell

I'm aiming to create PowerShell scripts that will:

1. Extract multiple zip files in a directory
2. Create archive zip files for multiple file types with the ability to add files to the zip if it already exists.

I cannot use `Compress-Archive` / `Expand-Archive` in PowerShell v4

This extracts test.zip but I need it to extract multiple .zip files at once using a wildcard:

```
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\test.zip', 'C:\')
```

This creates the zip file in the directory `"C:\$year\$month\$folder.zip"`, When I run the same script again with a new 'sample' file, it says it already exists.

I need to amend the script to say 'If the zip file exists, add the file to it'.

```
$year = Get-Date -Format 'Yr. yyyy'
$month = Get-Date -Format 'MMMM'
$folder = Get-Date -Format 'TESTddMMyyyy'
$source = "C:\$year\$month\$folder"
$destination = "C:\$year\$month\$folder.zip"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\$year\$month\$(Get-Date -Format 'TESTddMMyyyy')"
Move-Item 'C:\SAMPLE*' "C:\$year\$month\$(Get-Date -Format 'TESTddMMyyyy')"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[system.io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
Remove-Item $source -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` allow you to query for files in directories using wildcard matches.  You can then loop through the results and run the command you have on the returned files.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Test-Path $destination)
{
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]$ZipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($destination, ([System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update))
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($ZipFile, $source, (Split-Path $source -Leaf))
   $ZipFile.Dispose()
}
else
{
   [system.io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
}
Remove-Item $source -Force -Recurse
```